# CMS Made Simple - adding CAPTCHA to a form

Tags: forms, content-management-system, captcha, cmsmadesimple

I am new to CMS Made Simple and I am trying to add CAPTCHA to a form. I'm guessing this is done by installing a CAPTCHA moldule? I have installed the module but have no idea how to add it to the form I am using.

Has anyone done this before, or know of how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about CMS Made Simple, but it looks like it has a [captcha module](http://wiki.cmsmadesimple.org/index.php/User_Handbook/Admin_Panel/Extensions/Captcha) you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the CMSMS form builder module to make your form...

1. Under the tab catcha settings, check "Use Captcha to protect form submissions".
2. Captcha will automatically appear on your form.

You can go to the captcha module and select from different captcha libraries.